# Using the Google Ads linked service in Synapse or ADF, how do I know what the timerange of exported data is?

Tags: azure-synapse, google-ads-api, linked-service

If you are trying to export Google Ads data and you are using Synapse, there is a Linked Service that allows you to use a simple copy activity to land your data on a storage account or similar. Since there is no documentation what so ever, I am just going to share some insights with you here.

Answer (score 0):

Setup your Linked Service and Dataset and create a copy activity. Provide the table name for the table you want to extract:

[image]

After doing so, and running the pipeline. You might wonder what timerange your data contains. It contains yesterdays data, which the date column will also show. However, if you need to sum up Impressions, Clicks or similar, you will have to group your data campaign name and take the max value of the metric, instead of summing it up.

Why? Rows are running totals, and not individual observations.

[image]